# Terraform Azure - how to define multiple subnet IDs inside Firewall Setting for azurerm_cognitive_account

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, terraform-provider-azure

How do I add multiple subnet IDs inside the `network_acls.virtual_network_rules` for `azurerm_cognitive_account`?

I see this is possible from Azure Portal GUI. But can't find any code examples on [terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account) to do it.

##### Module:

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "azureai_multiservices" {
  for_each                      = { for aaimsa in var.aaimulti_services : aaimsa.name => aaimsa }
  name                          = each.value.name
  location                      = each.value.location
  resource_group_name           = each.value.resource_group_name
  kind                          = "CognitiveServices"
  sku_name                      = each.value.sku_name
  public_network_access_enabled = each.value.public_network_access_enabled
  custom_subdomain_name         = each.value.custom_subdomain_name

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.aaimsa_user_identities[each.value.name].id]
  }

  dynamic "network_acls" {
    for_each = each.value.acls
    iterator = acl
    content {
      default_action             = acl.value.default_action
      ip_rules                   = acl.value.ip_rules
      virtual_network_rules {
        subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.subnets[acl.value.allowed_subnet].id 
      }
    }
  }

  tags = merge(var.default_tags, each.value.tags)
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [  ]
  }
}
```

##### Portal:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to define multiple subnet IDs inside Firewall Setting for azurerm_cognitive_account and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To add multiple subnet IDs inside the `network_acls.virtual_network_rules` for an `azurerm_cognitive_account` in Terraform, you need to create a list of subnet IDs that you want to include and iterate over them using the `dynamic` block.

**My Terraform Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "sakavya"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example_subnet1" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "demovkvnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example_subnet2" {
  name                 = "default2"
  virtual_network_name = "demovkvnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example_identity" {
  name                = "vk-identity"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "example_cognitive_account" {
  name                          = "vk-cognitive-account"
  location                      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                          = "CognitiveServices"
  sku_name                      = "S0"

  public_network_access_enabled = true
  custom_subdomain_name         = "example-cognitive-custom-subdomain"

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example_identity.id]
  }

  network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

    virtual_network_rules {
      subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.example_subnet1.id
    }
    virtual_network_rules {
      subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.example_subnet2.id
    }
  }

  tags = {
    "environment" = "development"
  }
}
```

for **n** subnets we need to pass them in locals and configuration should be as mentioned.

```
locals {
  subnet_ids = [
    data.azurerm_subnet.example_subnet1.id,
    data.azurerm_subnet.example_subnet2.id,
    # Add more subnet IDs here
  ]
}

network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

    dynamic "virtual_network_rules" {
      for_each = toset(locals.subnet_ids)
      content {
        subnet_id = virtual_network_rules.value
      }
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to nest dynamic blocks within each other?